# Performance test of JAVA RMI based application using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Could you please suggest if it is possible to use Jmeter for performance testing of JAVA RMI based application. This application is a external product hence we do not have source code or classes available.

can you suggest a way to test this application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box there is no way, you will need to write some code using one of the following elements:

- [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request)
- [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter)

Given I don't know anything about RMI methods exposed by your application I cannot suggest any sample code, use the following reference material:

- [Getting Started Using Java™ RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html)
- [Use JMeter to Load Test RMI (Remote Method Invocation) Server](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/14/use-jmeter-to-load-test-rmi-remote-method-invocation-server/)

NB. JMeter uses RMI for communication between master and remote slaves so you can take a look at [RemoteJMeterEngineImpl](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.html) class to get an idea regarding how to implement your test scenario.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions , unfortunately it is not possible to test this application by Jmeter as well. Can you please suggest any tool which can help for performance testing of JAVA RMI application.                                                      I already tried HP loadrunner , it can not be used due to unavailability of source code.